# $filter "not groupTypes/any() " on Groups in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The following works in Graph Explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c eq 'Unified')
```

However, this does not:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=not groupTypes/any()
```

This returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Filter not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d0c9fac3-9ee4-4b92-8841-6dbefca2d150",
            "date": "2017-07-20T13:37:18"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I constructing the OData $filter the wrong way or is it really not supported? (use case: give me all groups *except* unified ones)

Answer (score 0):

The verb `not` isn't recognized by Graph. I expect what you're looking for here would be `ne` such as:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c ne 'Unified')`

You can read about the $filter parameter in the [Graph Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#filter).

Comment: Apparently this isn't a valid $filter either: Request_UnsupportedQuery. As an aside I am not sure if it would yield the same result as my approach: if Unified *and* another type are in the array, any should still get me this group.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the scenario? What kind of results are you looking to pull from the API?

Comment: Based on Odata, if you want to get all groups that are not Unified, I think you'd use the 'all' construct:  $filter=groupTypes/all(c:c ne 'Unified').  However all filters are not supported by Graph :).  Per Marc, what is it you are trying to do here?  We might be able to construct a different query for you.

Comment: The scenario is "Give me all groups that have zero elements in the groupTypes array". And yes, I did try all too... seems to not be possible at the moment.

Comment: Directory doesn't support the "not equals" operation.  It also doesn't support "equals null", but I heard some rumors that this latter one *could* be changing.  Don't have any dates though.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(a:a%20eq%20'unified')
```

You can read about it in Documentation - Reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview